# A Baire measure with different extensions to a Radon measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space. Let $\mu : \mathcal{B}a(X) \to [0, \infty)$ be a finite Baire measure where $\mathcal{B}a(X) := \sigma(C_b(X))$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the continuous (bounded) functions $C_b(X)$.

Facts:

- If $\mu$ is a tight Baire measure then $\mu$ has an extension to a Radon measure, i.e. a measure $\mu : \mathcal{B}(X) \to [0, \infty)$ defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(X)$ that is inner regular with respect to the compact sets on all Borel sets, i.e. $\mu(B) = \inf \{ \mu(K) \mid K \subseteq B,\, K \textrm{ compact} \}$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}(X)$ [Bogachev, "Measure Theory", 7.3.10].
- If in addition $X$ is completely regular then this Radon measure extension is unique [Bogachev, 7.3.3] (there can may be also Borel measure extensions of $\mu$ that are not Radon).
- Moreover, two Radon measures coincide if and only if they already coincide on the compact sets.

Is there an example of a Hausdorff space $X$ (that is necessarily not completely regular) and a Baire measure $\mu$ on $X$ that has two different Radon measure extensions? These Radon measures must be different on some compact set which is not contained in the Baire $\sigma$-algebra.